# Possible to link together libraries into one library, and resolve internal function calls?

Tags: linker, g++

I am working on a system with hundreds of excecutables.  Each executable fully links in various .a libraries statically.  Shared libraries are not an option right now.  A fully rebuild is quite slow.  Bottle neck seems to be linking since each executable has to be relinked and there are hundreds.

Is it possible to create a "master" library of all the libraries where internal function calls are resolved,  then use this master library when linking the binaries ?  The idea being that time would be saved due to internal library calls already being resolved.  ( there are many calls between the libraries ).

We do not use clang and I don't believe incremental linking is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a "master" library

Sure: `ld -r -o master.o --whole-archive libfoo.a libbar.a ...` should do it.

There is a high chance that each of your binaries will become larger ([explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html)).

Also, if you are using `ELF`, you may get significantly faster links using the (new) [Gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)).

Finally, if you are building on a powerful machine with lots of RAM (as you should), running `make -j12` or even higher should speed things up considerably by executing many links in parallel. This requires correct `Makefile` structure and correct dependencies (which you *should* have anyway for correctness of your builds).